# Using Palette with picasso

Tags: android, retrofit, picasso, palette

I am using palette to get colors and setting it to text and background color. I am following as per the following post to use palette with picasso

http://jakewharton.com/coercing-picasso-to-play-with-palette/

I am successfully able to apply fetch colors using palette the first time , but when I get a 304 not modified status , the onSuccess() is not called and the palette transformation is not applied

```
 PaletteTransformation paletteTransformation = new PaletteTransformation();
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).
                transform(paletteTransformation).
                into(holder.characterImage, new Callback.EmptyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        super.onSuccess();
                        Palette palette = paletteTransformation.getPalette();
                        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Roboto-Thin.ttf");
                        holder.characterName.setTypeface(typeface);
                        if (palette != null) {
                            Palette.Swatch swatch =  palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                            holder.characterName.setBackgroundColor(palette.getVibrantColor(0));
                            if(swatch!=null)
                                holder.characterName.setTextColor(swatch.getTitleTextColor());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I ended up using this library https://github.com/florent37/PicassoPalette

Answer (score 0):

you should get an image from Picasso and convert it to bitmap.
because Palette works with Bitmap.
and When your Bitmap gets ready, use this code to getting color from Bitmap with Palette:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) collapsingImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Palette palette = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();

color1 = palette.getDominantColor(getResources().getColor(defaultColor));
color2 = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(getResources().getColor(defaultColor));
color3 = palette.getVibrantColor(getResources().getColor(defaultColor));
```

if you have Bitmap don't need this line(You get Bitmap from Picasso):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) collapsingImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

and this is the needed of these codes :

```
int defaultColor = R.color.colorPrimary;
public static int color1, color2, color3;
```